# I have a button trying to run a alert but it wont work?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a button to run a function and it wont work so i am trying to see if the button works at all. I am trying to just add a alert to the button and no luck. Any sugestions?

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="alert("hi")">Click me</button>
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: try `alert('hi')` instead of `alert("hi")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes around "hi" are escaping your HTML quotes. Try using single quotes or escaping your double quotes by using `&quot;` instead.

For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="alert('hi')">Click me</button>
  </body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="alert('hi')">Click me</button>
  </body>   
</html>
```

You can't use " "content" " in html, it will give a syntax error. Use " 'content' " instead so the HTML will be parsed correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="Myalert()">Click me</button>
    <script>
       function Myalert(){
         alert('hi');
       }
    </script>

  </body>   
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

> In Case you prefer using Jquery along with HTML
>
> HTML

```
  <button id="idforhi">Click me</button>
```

> JQuery

```
 $('#idforhi').click(function(){
  alert('hi');
 });
```

Comment: Issue #1: The question wasn't tagged with jQuery, so suggesting a jQuery solution is inappropriate. Issue #2: your code example won't work because you forgot the close parenthesis.